# Public app list of chrome apps

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

Is there a way to get a list of all the apps from a developer? Basically similar to the developer dashboard, but public. The only way I found is to do a search by the username, but doesn't show all (there's also 'related' tab that shows some but not all).

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking on a non-google website that has an index, e.g. [Chromebeat search - authorwebsite=google.com](https://www.chromebeat.com/advancedsearch?authorwebsite=google.com)